# MongoDB Replica Set CPU load

Tags: mongodb

I am running a fairly standard MongoDB (3.0.5) replica set with 1 primary and 2 secondaries. My PHP application's read preference is primary, so no reads take place on the secondaries - they are only for failover. I am running a load test on my application, which creates around 600 queries / updates per second. The operations are all being run against a collection that has ~500,000 documents. However, the queries are optimized and supported by indexes. Any query will not take longer than 40ms max.

My problem is that I am getting a quite high CPU load on all 3 nodes (200% - 300%) - sometimes the load on the secondaries is even higher than on the primary. Disk IO and RAM usage seem to be okay - at least they are not hitting any limits.

The primary's log file contains a huge amount of getmore oplog queries - I would guess that any operation on the primary creates an oplog query. It appears to me that this is too much replication overhead but I don't have any prior experience with MongoDB under load and I don't have any key figures.

As the setup will have to tolerate even more load in production, my question is whether the replication overhead is to be expected and whether it's normal that the CPU load goes up that high, even on the secondaries or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it this way. Whatever data-changing operation happens on the primary, it also needs to happen on every secondary. If there are many such operations and they create high CPU load on the primary, well, then the same situation will repeat itself on the secondaries.

Of course, in your case you'd expect the primary's CPU to be more stressed, because in addition to the writes it also handles all the reads. Probably, in your scenario, reads are relatively light and there aren't many of them when compared to the amount of writes. This would explain why the load on the primary is roughly the same as on the secondaries.

> my question is whether the replication overhead is to be expected

What you call replication overhead I see as the nature of replication. A primary stressed by writes results in all secondaries being stressed by writes as well.

> and whether it's normal that the CPU load goes up that high, even on the secondaries

You have 600 write queries per second and your RAM and disk are not stressed, to me this signifies that you've set up your indexes properly. High CPU load is expected with this amount of write operations per second, because the indexes are being used intensively.

Please keep in mind that once you have gathered more data, the indexes and the memory-mapped data may not fit into memory anymore, and then both the RAM and the disk will be stressed, while CPU is unlikely to be under high load anymore. In this situation, you will probably want to either add more RAM or look into [**sharding**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/).